# Generator Function which calculates mean of several values in Python

Tags: python, function, statistics, generator, mean

I have a problem with a code in Python. I would like to create a generator function, which will calculate the mean value of several or indefinitely large of numbers. I think I should use commands like:
       *args (for giving from the keyboard numbers) ,import statistics(for thw calculation of mean value) but I can not compose it.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your problem is? Do you know how to calculate the mean of numbers? Do you know how to write a generator function? Do you know how to pass input to a generator function?

Comment: The main problem in how to compose thew generator function in order to put via input command several number of integer numbers. thw problem in the generator function

Comment: What have you tried to solve that specific problem? Do you want the generator to get ``input`` by itself, or should it be passed in from the outside? Do you want the generator to receive input once on creation, or should it continuously be fed new input?

Comment: def f1(*args): 
    for i in args:
        print(mean)
   return

Comment: This is my full code but I cant make it to worfk

Comment: That code snippet is neither a generator, nor does it take ``input``. Are you aware how to write a basic generator?

Comment: The exersice I have to do is to write a generator function which can get a plenty of numbers (integer) and return the mean of the values. Could you helpo me to compose the commands fro the generator function?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We can help you with specific, individual problems *with existing code*. We can also explain specific, individual problems *if you understand the basics for them*. Please see the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also try to understand the basic concepts you are asking about, so that you can clearly describe what you even need.

Comment: I solved it. I made a syntax mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that while you know what you want (the mean value of numbers), you aren't really clear on how you want to approach your desired goal, and furthermore you seem to be somewhat confused with the fundamentals of writing python.

<s>Like what [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) asked, you haven't indicated much information on how you'd like your generator function to work.</s>

**Edit:** 
From your comment (and this should really be part of your question), this is the code you've tried:

```py
def f1(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(mean)
    return
```

### Issues with your question / attempted solution

There are several things from your question and attempted solution that I'd like to cover.

- Firstly, you shouldn't need to `import statistics` because calculating mean is a straightforward thing.
- Secondly, you mentioned

  > I would like to create a generator function, which will calculate the mean value of several or indefinitely large of numbers.

  However, in your code you iterate through the list of numbers you pass to your function `f1` and print out the value of mean (where was this variable even defined?).
- There is no need for the `return` keyword if you're only trying to print out values
- Your function isn't a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) as it's not an iterator, something you can iterate from.
- You seem to want input from `stdin` (typing values in to the terminal), but you don't even have any `input()` calls anywhere.

### What you need:

You don't actually need a "generator" as defined by the python documentation.
What you need is just a simple function to:

1. Take keyboard input, for example `1,2,3,4,5`
2. Parse that input into a python list of integers
3. Calculate the average of that list
4. Print that average

I'll now walk you through how to do these 4 things in python.

---

#### 1. Taking keyboard input

This is done is with the [`input()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). The variable you assign the function to will take the value of the user's input, while whatever string you place as an argument to the function will be displayed as a prompt for a user to give input.

```
message = 'Please enter a comma-separated list of numbers:'
numbers = input(message)
```

#### 2. Parsing keyboard input into a python list of integers

Based on my prompt in the part above, I will expect users to type in a bunch of numbers separated by commas. However, we will not be able to use that input for calculation as it's a string. We would like to convert that string into a list of integers.

The python string class has a class method `split()`. The string it operates on is converted into a list, while the argument to the method will be character used to "split" the list.

```
# If numbers was a string `1,2,3`, then num_list will be a list `['1','2','3']`
num_list = numbers.split(',')
```

Now note that `num_list` is still a list of strings when what we need is a list of integers. We can use a for loop to iterate through the list to cast the strings to integers.

```py
# Create a new list
new_num_list = []
# Iterate through the old list
for num in num_list:
    # We use append() to append items to the new number list
    new_num_list.append(int(num))
```

Alternatively, an easier way would be to use a `list comprehension`

```
new_num_list = [int(num) for num in num_list]
```

#### 3. Calculating the average of that list

Now that we have the numbers in a list, we simply get the total sum of the numbers in the list, and divide that sum by the number of values in the list.

```py
# Using len() on a list tells us the length of the list (how many values are in the list)
number_of_numbers = len(new_num_list)

# Using sum() gives us the sum of values in the list
sum_of_numbers = sum(new_num_list)

# Calculate the average
average = sum_of_numbers/number_of_numbers
```

#### 4. Printing the average

This is straightforward: `print(average)`

---

#### Putting it all together as a function

```
def f1():
    # Get input
    message = 'Please enter a comma-separated list of numbers:'
    numbers = input(message)

    # Parse input into list of integers
    num_list = numbers.split(',')
    new_num_list = [int(num) for num in num_list]

    # Calculate average
    number_of_numbers = len(new_num_list)
    sum_of_numbers = sum(new_num_list)
    average = sum_of_numbers/number_of_numbers

    # Output
    print(average)
```

Caveats:
Input must be comma separated numbers. If you passed in `1,a,b,c` or `1 , 2,3` the code would break.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much. I have one last qusetion. 
The function must return successively (according to the function of a generator) the square of the difference of each value from the average of all the values ​​given as input.If I would like to print all above how shoud I have to write it?

Comment: Surely with the explanation I gave in my solution you could figure it out? You simply have to do additional calculations on top of finding the average. Like what @MisterMiyagi said, stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please put in the bare minimum of effort (attempting it yourself). By not doing so and learning from it, you are only doing a disservice to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Question wasn't clear,
You might be looking for this code:

```
def mean(*args):
    print(sum(args) / len(args))
```

-- Edit:
Above code is not a Generator function, for calculating mean number you need a simple function not a generator, 
to make the above function work simply call the function:

```
mean(10,12,13)
```

if you need to get the numbers from user input, use the function in this way:

```
string = input("Enter all numbers in space separated format")
strings_of_numbers = string.split()  # creating a list of string_numbers 
list_of_numbers = [int(i) for i in strings_of_numbers]  # converting string numbers to integers
mean(*list_of_numbers)  # calling function with args
```

Comment: First of all thank you, but in screen the result it does  not showing. And I can not put the values I would like - spesific numbers I mean

Comment: This is not a generator function.

Comment: As checking of the right running of the code, the 
pronunciation of the exersice says that if you run the code and if you give as input parameters the numbers 3,4,5 then function will return the number 4 in screen (which is the mean number of the numbers 3,4 and 5)